# VimCrypt, build passses, tests fail, why?

Tags: c, vim

In this [github](https://github.com/nowox/vim-blowfish) repository, I have set up a very small project which takes two files from Vim 7.4:

- blowfish.c
- sha256.c

I wrapped a `main` and the missing declarations around this in order to build the project. The good news is I can build the project. The bad news is that the self-tests fail. I really don't understand why and I don't know in which direction I should search.

I tried to build Vim on the same machine from the mercurial sources and run the self-tests. They pass. I used the same build options, the same compiler and the same sources.

What did I miss?

I found that the second check of the blowfish tables fails. I don't know why.

Comment: I don't think Stackoverflow is for asking people to debug your pet project, sorry.

Comment: I'm not asking for debugging. I am asking for a way to investigate. Both project builds, the sources are mostly common and the behavior is not the same. I assume I am missing something that a c programmer might know... Nothing related to any pet project.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your program?

Comment: @JS1, No I didn't I tried to use a lot of `printf`. I will try